# Is there a way to use MySQL's JSON_EXTRACT with integer keys in JSON string?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Is it possible to use `JSON_EXTRACT` with integer keys?

I want to extract `[273, 140]` from below, but the SQL does not work ...

```
SELECT json_extract('{"1": [273, 140], "2": [273.5, 198.5], "3": [209, 191]}', '$.1');
```

I am trying to use syntax from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path

I get error:

```
ERROR 3143 (42000): Invalid JSON path expression. 
The error is around character position 3
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use double quotes around the key if it is a number. This works:

```
select json_extract('{"1": [273, 140], "2": [273.5, 198.5], "3": [209, 191]}', '$."1"');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.